# how to display the values in a text-box by retrieving that values from the database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, jsp, netbeans

I'm doing a database project. I have a webpage where i have 5 textboxes. In one of the textboxes, when it is on focus, I should show to the user the values present in the database. I know how to retrieve using javascript and AJAX but am not able to display  the retrieved values in the textbox.I tried a lot but couldn't get it.

Can anyone help me in doing this?

The code is as follows:

```
function showData(){ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
    var id=document.getElementById("vendor_name").value;
    var url="ftc_id.jsp";
    url=url+"?vendor_name="+id;
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged(){ 
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){ 
        var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText; 
        var strar = showdata.split(":");
        if(strar.length>1){
            var strname = strar[1];
            document.getElementById("vendor_address").value= strar[1];
            document.getElementById("vendor_contact_no").value= strar[2];
            document.getElementById("currency").value= strar[3];
            document.getElementById("po_value_rs").value= strar[4];
        }
```

display I m using the showData string as above. To autocomplete I have to make some changes here:

```
input type="text" id="vendor_name" name="vendor_name" onkeyup="showData();
```

Comment: are u getting results as json string?

Comment: do you, by any chance, mean an "auto-complete"?

Comment: @joseph ya i need the autocomplete feature

Comment: @FahimParkar i used it i didnot get it

Comment: @mini no i m not getting that also

Comment: could you provide code please...

Comment: @fahimPrakar which code js code or jsp code?

Comment: @FahimParkar i havew attached the codes ah

Comment: I don't see the code as I have edited it and it is waiting for review :(

Comment: This is to retrieve the strings:                                   var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText; 
    var strar = showdata.split(":");
      if(strar.length>1){
        var strname = strar[1];
        document.getElementById("vendor_address").value= strar[1];
       document.getElementById("vendor_contact_no").value= strar[2];
        document.getElementById("currency").value= strar[3];
        document.getElementById("po_value_rs").value= strar[4];
         }

Comment: This I am using to display:    <td>vendor_name:</td><td><input type="text" id="vendor_name" name="vendor_name" onkeyup="showData();"/></td>

Comment: add code in question... not in comment... also format the code when you show...

Comment: What do you get if you `alert("showdata = '"+ showdata +"'");` in your stateChanged() function?

Comment: @Neal Did you consider the use of JQuery to perform that Work and also JQuery Autocomplete Plugin to make the auto-completing ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `showData()` on `onkeyup` try to call function on `onfocus` instead of `onkeyup`. Other than that I cant see any error on your given code.